# Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool Slow

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling

I have a web application that runs on Tomcat 9. For a while I had been using a single JDBC Connection object to handle all requests but I knew I would have to change this to a connection pool in the future. Well, that day has come and now the application runs significantly slower (almost exactly 3x slower). The only difference between the fast build and the slow build is the use of a connection pool and I can consistently generate the same results. The testing is being done on the exact same systems with the exact same configurations (e.g., logging).

The application is not that database intensive so the difference in transaction processing time is rather surprising to me. Without the connection pool a transaction (which has 2 calls to the web service which results in, at most, 2 DB reads and 2 DB writes) takes 5 seconds to process. With the connection pool, the exact same sequence of calls takes 15 seconds to complete.

Code to retrieve connection:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolProperties;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class UsernamePasswordConnectionRetriever implements IConnectionRetriever {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UsernamePasswordConnectionRetriever.class);
    private final DataSource datasource;

    public UsernamePasswordConnectionRetriever(String driver, String url, String username, String password) {
        PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
        p.setUrl(url);
        p.setDriverClassName(driver);
        p.setUsername(username);
        p.setPassword(password);
        p.setJmxEnabled(false);
        p.setTestWhileIdle(false);
        p.setTestOnBorrow(false);
        p.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
        p.setTestOnReturn(false);
        p.setValidationInterval(90000);
        p.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(30000);
        p.setMaxActive(200);
        p.setInitialSize(2);
        p.setMaxWait(0);
        p.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(60);
        p.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(30000);
        p.setMinIdle(10);
        p.setLogAbandoned(true);
        p.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
        p.setJdbcInterceptors(
          "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;"+
          "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer");
        datasource = new DataSource();
        datasource.setPoolProperties(p);
    }   

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        LOGGER.debug("DB connection pool info: {} active, {} idle", datasource.getNumActive(), datasource.getNumIdle());
        return datasource.getConnection();
    }

}
```

The *getConnection* method is called by the caller in a *try-with-resources* block with the connection being the resource so I know it is getting closed. Furthermore, I always see the same log entry of "*DB connection pool info: 0 active, 2 idle*" so that provides extra assurance that the connections are not being left open.

I have played around with some variants of those setters but still haven't seen any real change in the performance. I have also turned off slf4j logging and that difference was almost negligible.

Any advice on how I can get better performance and still use a connection pool?

**Edit** I should add that the database being used here is MySQL and the system is being tested on a Windows Server 2016 box. We also do testing on Linux but the results I have posted all came from the Windows test server.

Comment: How is this `UsernamePasswordConnectionRetriever` being used? Do you create a single instance that is shared or do you recreate this when needed?

Comment: *DB connection pool info: 0 active, 2 idle* - try increasing the initial size to some thing greater

Comment: @M.Deinum Only one instance of it is created ever. That instance is shared throughout the lifetime of the application.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I tried increasing the initial size to 10 and that didn't make a difference. That log entry makes me think it doesn't run out of available connections so I am not sure if increasing the size would make much of a difference.

Comment: That's strange. I'd switch on all logging and I'd try to find out what part takes the time (getting the connection, execution, ...). I'd also try with some minimal application, doing just one simple read or alike, hoping that once it gets simple, you can spot the problem. I'd also remove all unnecessary settings hoping that the defaults are good enough (not completely broken). It simply must work.

Comment: Datasource should be instanciated at [container level](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#How_to_use) and then referred in your code through JNDI.